# How can I achieve nested queries in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables followers and users...
followers table have follower and followee id . Now I would like to retrieve the followers/followees for an user.

```
    $followers_id=Follower::where('followee_id',$user->id)->select('follower_id')->get();
    $following_id=Follower::where('follower_id',$user->id)->select('followee_id')->get();
    $followers=User::where('id',$followers_id->follower_id)->take(15)->get();
    $following=User::where('id',$following_id->followee_id)->take(15)->get();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define a **many-to-many** relation in your User class, that would use the intermediate **followers** table:

```
public function followers() {
  $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'followee_id', 'follower_id');
}
```

Now you should be able to get a list of followers of given user by simply accessing:

```
$followers = $user->followers;
```